# PostgreSQL 9.6 - can't connect to database created from a custom template database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have created a database `foo` which I am using as a template database to create other databases from.

I am running all PostgreSQL in a Docker container (not sure if that is relevant to the problem at hand).

#### Here is the (truncated) SQL

```
CREATE DATABASE foo WITH ENCODING 'UTF8' template0;
\i db_schema_foo.sql
-- Create extensions
-- Initialise db with data etc ...

CREATE DATABASE foobar TEMPLATE foo;
```

#### (Truncated) console output:

```
CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "postgres".
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
 ...
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE INDEX
CREATE DATABASE
FATAL:  database "foobar" does not exist
psql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_databases.sql:82: \connect: FATAL:  database "foobar" does not exist
```

From the console, I'm assuming that both `foo` and `foobar` are created - so why can't I connect to database `foobar`?

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks for spotting and pointing that out. I made a mistake in my truncated question. I have corrected the output now.

Comment: @VaoTsun The problem is that because PostgreSQL is running in a container, I don't know how to access its logs to see if an error occurred whilst creating database `foobar`. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @VaoTsun I'm running a standard PG binary pulled from dockerhub. I have not set any custom flags. HTH

Comment: if you would disclose real database names - the question would be answere d in seconds :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `psql` command `\l` to see which databases exist.

I would expect database `foobar` to not exist.

That would mean that the `CREATE DATABASE` statement has failed.
Can you get the error message for that?

My suspicion is that creating the database failed because you were still connected to the template database `foo`. You can only use a database with no active connections as template.

Comment: I changed database connection to another table, after creating `foobar` but before attempting to connect to `foobar` and I got the same error message: `database foobar does not exist`. The problem is that because PostgreSQL is running in a container, I don't know how to access its logs to see if an error occured whilst creating database `foobar`.

Comment: It turns out it was a rather mundane error. It was a capitalisation issue. I was creating database `Foobar` and attempting to connect to `Foobar`, not realising that PostgreSQL had 'normalised the database name to `foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE DATABASE` in output means either that databse was successfully created, if there would be error and no warning, like here:

```
t=# set client_min_messages TO fatal;
SET
t=# create database t;
t=# set client_min_messages TO warning;
SET
t=# create database t;
ERROR:  database "t" already exists
```

there would not be such output - `CREATE DATABASE`
so next line `FATAL:  database "foobar" does not exist` (together with knowledge database was created) leads to idea that OP is connecting to different cluser, or different database

In private chat we found that database created was *"Foobar"* and database attempting to connect was *Foobar* and thus *"foobar"*, which does not exist indeed, as *"Foobar"* does